# Cannot shut down Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: command-line, 14.04, windows, power-management, shutdown

this is my first time using Ubuntu 14.04 version.

I'm not sure what I've done, but I can't shut down my laptop. But if I log in as the guest, then it will shut down if I press the button and I'm not getting used to terminal. How can I solve the problem?

Comment: Please be specific with your question. Something like what happened instead of shutdown (black screen, nothing happened), how you shutting down your laptop, after what event (download software, edit file, or so) this happened, etc.
Cheers.

Comment: Do you use cairo-dock?

Answer (score 4):

A general (and hard) way to shutdown your computer is

- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> for showing terminal
- Type `sudo shutdown -h now` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
- Type in your password (if prompted) press <kbd>Enter</kbd> again
- Wait sometime

Comment: What happen if I always shutdown   the pc with  this command   ?

Comment: If you've succeed using this command, then it has no side-effect as far as I experienced. But, be aware of any unsaved work you have. Better closing all programs first.